# Interface inheritance - hiding method from parent interface - why can I have both methods in the implementing class?

Tags: c#, interface, method-hiding

I am trying to understand how the inheritance of interfaces works. When an interface inherits another interface but has a method with the same signature, the compiler gives a warning that the base member is hidden (and this seems logical).

However, when I later implement the child interface in a class, I have to implement both the parent and the child interface method having the same signature and this confuses me... I thought that when the parent member is hidden I will need to implement only the child interface method?

(I came upon this while looking at `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces)

```
interface IMyBase
{
    int DoSomething();
}

interface IMyDerived:IMyBase
{
    int DoSomething();
}


class myClass : IMyDerived
{
    int IMyDerived.DoSomething()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int IMyBase.DoSomething()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're explicitly implementing the interfaces. In that case inheritance is off the table.

Comment: the interface members cannot be hidden there are not classes

Comment: Just don't put `DoSomething()` in `IMyDerived`, it already inherits it from `IMyBase`. Putting it in this interface adds zero value. I'm actually surprised the compiler doesn't complain about this? I'd expect at least a warning.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to implement both the parent and the child interface method having the same signature and this confuses me

So what do you expect will happen if you do this?

```
IMyBase x = new myClass();

x.DoSomething();
```

There is two methods, `IMyBase.Something` and `IMyDerived.Something`, both have to exist because both can be called. `myClass` still implements `IMyBase`, the interface was not hidden in any way.

Comment: In this case what does mean the compiler's message 
"MyDerived.DoSomething()' hides inherited member 'IMyBase.DoSomething()'..."?
It is hidden in which context?

Comment: @Jaxx When calling through an `IMyDerived` type, `IMyBase.DoSomething` is hidden. You'd have to cast to `IMyBase` first to access *that* method.